# Determine how many characters there are after a certain character in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield

I am working with a `UITextField` and numerical input. I need to determine how many characters there are AFTER a specific character(.). Is this possible with `NSString` methods at all, if so How? I have tried using the `shouldReplaceCharacters`: method without much success.

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSUInteger *position = [givenString rangeOfString:@"."].location;
NSUInteger result = givenString.length - position - 1;
```

or alternative:

```
NSArray *splittedString = [givenString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSUInteger count = [splittedString count];
if (count > 1) {
     NSString *stringAfterDot = (NSString*)[splittedString objectAtIndex:1];
     NSUInteger result = stringAfterDot.length;
     (...)
}
```

First one will return number of characters after first dot, second will return number of characters between first and second dot (or the end of the string, if there's no second dot).

Comment: NSUInteger is a type and therefore I don't believe it needs a pointer.